# Why success code is returned instead of 304 code when ETag is the same

Tags: etag, http-status-code-304

I am working on cache issue on my website and I am really confused by ETag. Please have a look at request and response headers of style.css:

**Request headers:**

```
 Accept text/css,*/*;q=0.1
 Accept-Encoding:   gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language:   en-US,en;q=0.5
 Cache-Control: max-age=0
 Connection:    keep-alive
 Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1740290458.156863471…dhWtcW6i-vez0qPoXLRE%22%3B%7D
 Host:  mysite.com
 If-Modified-Since: Tue, 14 May 2019 10:50:56 GMT
 If-None-Match: "92c-588d6ceb7e7f1;5829ea1c460e9-gzip"
 Referer:   mysite.com/
 User-Agent:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
```

**Response header:**

```
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Connection:    Keep-Alive
 Content-Encoding:  gzip
 Content-Length:    670
 Content-Type:  text/css
 Date:  Mon, 16 Sep 2019 12:14:37 GMT
 ETag:  "92c-588d6ceb7e7f1;5829ea1c460e9-gzip"
 Keep-Alive:    timeout=5, max=91
 Last-Modified: Tue, 14 May 2019 10:50:56 GMT
 Server:    Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
 Vary:  Accept-Encoding
```

As you see there is "If-None-Match" directive in request header and its value is the same as ETag value is returned by server in response header. So the same value means resource(css file) doesn't have changed on the server so I expected to get 304 http status code,but 200 is received. Event if press F5 key multi times.
This is what confused me! Is it my misunderstand of ETag?

Comment: `Cache-Control: max-age=0` might be interfering here I guess?

Comment: @04FS As I read in articles max-age is related to if send a new request to server or read from browser cache,but the ETag is related to server response after the request is receive by server. So ETag and max-age are two different concept.

Comment: These are not completely independent concepts though - if you specify how caching should be handled in multiple ways, those need to “match”, otherwise you will get conflicts.